# Где можно более углубленно изучить ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет, ребят! Изучал ASP.NET Core MVC по гайдам(метанинт, видео). Написал свой проект на MVC. Основные моменты понял. Но это все поверхностно. Где можно глубже изучить MVC???

Answer (score 0):

Есть множество курсов по ASP.NET Core на [Udemy](https://udemy.com), хороших и разных, там в основном на английском языке, но есть и на русском. Просто выбирайте курсы с максимальным рейтингом и те что по новее... Оплатить можете через виртуальную карту из РФ.
Можете так же посмотреть кое-что на [ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/@learnprofionline/about).